# Data Attrbute - get and set in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I have a number of tables on my page with the data attribute that I need to access in my document ready function, as follows, and also I show the HTML.

```
$('.accountsHoldingTable').DataTable({
    dom: 'tB',
    responsive: true,
    "lengthMenu": [[25, 50, 100, -1], [25, 50, 100, "All"]],
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            filename: "Positions " +  $(this).data("ttitle") + " " + today.toDateString()
        }
    ],
});
```

```xml
<table     id = "accountsHoldingTable" 
  data-ttitle = "my file name" 
        class = "headerSet table table-bordered display hover no-wrap dataTables accountsHoldingTable" 
        style = "width: 100%">
```

However, this gives me a result of

> "Positions undefined Mon Dec 04 2017 (2).xlsx"

How do I do this properly so that `undefined` is replaced by the `data-ttitle` value?

Comment: Can your html markup to the question please? its not all that clear what you are asking

Comment: The html is there already.

Comment: so it is. Apologies.

Comment: Use `$(this).attr('data-ttitle')` to get the current attribute value, not as it is parsed (or not) on page load. `The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values are then stored internally in jQuery).`

Comment: Sounds like an answer to me @A.Wolff ;)

Comment: The context of `this` is not what you think it is.  It's probably the global context unless you're calling the code above from a function.  It's not the jQuery context for each table that matches that class.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you are using `this` in the wrong context. See if this code accomplishes what you are are attempting to achieve:

```
$('.accountsHoldingTable').each(function(i, val) {
   $(this).DataTable({
     dom: 'tB',
     responsive: true,
     lengthMenu: [[25, 50, 100, -1], [25, 50, 100, "All"]],
     buttons: [
       {
          extend: 'excelHtml5',
          filename: "Positions " +  $(this).data("ttitle") + " " + today.toDateString()
       }
     ]
  });
});
```

Comment: Indeed it does. Thanks!